# Problem with ubuntu titlebar color

Tags: gnome, software-center, themes

I'm trying to change the color of my title bar on Ubuntu. More specifically I'm attempting to modify the color that the application bar should have when it's in focus and in the backdrop phase. The modification works correctly for system apps like Settings, but for apps like VSCode and Brave, the modification is the opposite. Let me explain with a practical example: I want the application bar to have the color #303440 when it's in focus and #1e222a when it's in the backdrop. This works correctly for all system apps except Brave and Visual Studio Code. In these cases, when they are in focus, they assume the color #1e222a, and when they are in the backdrop, they assume the color #303440.

I've already edited the gtk3 and gtk4 files, but the result hasn't changed. My impression is that non-system applications use a different type of window, as I have also modified the border radius for windows, but VSCode, Brave, and other non-native apps don't seem to reflect these changes.

I conducted another test to support this hypothesis: I launched a very simple Java app that I created, and the window that Linux provided for it has the same issue as VSCode and Brave, so it seems like Linux is providing a certain type of window for third-party apps. If that's the case, I would like to understand how to modify it.

[image: Impostation are in focus]

[image: vscode are in focus]

[image: My java app are in focus]

Below are my Gtk3 and Gtk4 files that I've modified.

gtk3 file:

[gtk3 file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LyKm9KRJFalU30f5uVPTqfQYutkZWODn/view?usp=sharing)

gtk4 file:

[gtk4 file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19o-ebcSZ6PuraVWLPKN9jgu0XlF2DFsl/view?usp=sharing)